# convert image to (None, 224, 224, 3) in tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensor

i want to convert my image data into (None, 224, 224, 3) , ive tried to using np.reshape (None, 224,224,3) the output says none is not integer, what should i do? thanks in advance
here is my code

```
testdata1= cv2.imread("/content/gdrive/My Drive/cnn/widya/p/daging(15).jpg", cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
testdata1=cv2.resize(testdata1, (224, 224),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
testdata1=np.array(testdata1)
testdata1 = testdata1.astype('float32')
testdata1= np.reshape(testdata1,[224,224,3] )
```

here is my error

```
 ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_4: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(32, 224, 3)
```

Comment: The error appears unrelated to the code you show. Please show where the error actually happens, and describe the shape and dtype of the input causing the problem. The found shape is clearly not 224x224x3

Answer (score -2):

Use `numpy.expand_dims(data, axis=0)`